# Store duplicate keys in a key value pair in Angular

Tags: javascript, angular

How can I store duplicate keys in a key value pair in Angular ?

For eg -

I want to store -

```
101 , 999
101 , 989
101 , 987
102 , 888
102 , 887
```

I tried with this -

```
    commentMap = new Map<number, number>();
    this.commentMap.set(101,999);
    this.commentMap.set(101,989);
    this.commentMap.set(101,987);
    this.commentMap.set(102,888);
    this.commentMap.set(102,887);
```

I tried doing this but this allows only unique key values , any way I can store in any data structure like this in angular ?

Comment: you can't. Map in typescript is like a dictionary or like an object, key must be unique.

Comment: Any other way to achieve this ? @A.T.

Comment: Use an array for the values..  `new Map<number, number[]>();`.    And then -> `commentMap.set(101,[999, 989, 987]);`

Answer (score 1):

The `Map` object holds key-value pairs so you need a different types for the key/value. You can change the value type to an array of numbers:

```
commentMap = new Map<number, number[]>();
commentMap.set(102,[888, 887]);
```

And now you can fetch it like so:

```
commentMap.get(102); // [888, 887]
```